# Mut variable assing after borrowed to build a nested tree like structure through iteration

Tags: rust

I am building a tree like structure, collecting references using a `res` variable as temporary variable:

```rust
pub enum JSb<'a, Item> {
    Start(Item),
    Move(Jbs<'a, Item>),
}

pub struct Jbs<'a, Item> {
    before: &'a JSb<'a, Item>,
    after: Item,
}

impl<'a, Item> Jbs<'a, Item> {
    pub fn new(before: &'a JSb<'a, Item>, after: Item) -> Self {
        Jbs { before, after }
    }
}

fn hello<'a>() -> JSb<'a, u8> {
    let mut res = JSb::Start(3);

    for i in 1..3 {
        let x = JSb::Move(Jbs::new(&res, i));
        res = x
    }
    res
}
```

```
error: cannot assign to `res` because it is borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:22:9
   |
17 | fn hello<'a>() -> JSb<'a, u8> {
   |          -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
21 |         let x = JSb::Move(Jbs::new(&res, i));
   |                                    ---- `res` is borrowed here
22 |         res = x
   |         ^^^^^^^ `res` is assigned to here but it was already borrowed
23 |     }
24 |     res
   |     --- returning this value requires that `res` is borrowed for `'a`

error: cannot return value referencing local variable `res`
  --> src/lib.rs:24:5
   |
21 |         let x = JSb::Move(Jbs::new(&res, i));
   |                                    ---- `res` is borrowed here
...
24 |     res
   |     ^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Not sure how to make this compile, and do what I want.
I can restructure the structs if needed for a more precise simple usage.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eb9107da6a87a8d7d2493ae714247c22

Comment: If you can make `Jbs` own `before`, [great](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=58c2d6917ea50ce224800b80aac92e6c). If not, you can't do it. It's simple.

Comment: Keep in mind there are different kinds of ownership, e.g. `Rc`.

Comment: Keep in mind, I am looking for exclusive I love rust ways of doing a Tree like structure, and note that I am using Bitboards to store the chess positions. Some way to link moves and position transitions with some additional extra data.

Comment: I'm unsure what `fn hello<'a>() -> JSb<'a, u8>` is supposed to be - as this function doesn't have any input parameters, `'a` **must** be `'static`, from my understanding. What else should it be? To be more specific, it cannot be a lifetime to a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem in your example is ownership.

In Rust, every element must have exactly one owner at all times. But, the thing you return is only one element of the tree, all the others are referenced in the `before` member, **by reference**. And if the returned element doesn't **own** them (as it can't, being just a reference), that means that they **must** be owned by the function itself, and will get destroyed at the end of it.

Further evidence of this is the function signature `fn hello<'a>() -> JSb<'a, u8>` - A lifetime only makes sense if it references something. But in this case, only the **return** type has a lifetime; a lifetime in a return type only makes sense if it references one of the input parameters. A lifetime is always a **dependency** to something else, and if you only have it in the return type, there is nothing it could possibly depend on. So the only way this would make sense is if `'a` is `'static`, which is probably not what you want.

There are multiple ways to solve this - but not with lifetimes, I'm afraid. Linked list type data structures are [one of the harder problems in Rust](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

There are two ways to solve this:

- with recursive ownership (every parent has a `Vec<Box<>>` of all of his children, and the return value of the function is the root object)
- with shared reference counters (`Rc<RefCell<>>`/`Arc<Mutex<>>`)

In your case, it would easily be rewritable with `Box`, as every element (in your example) only has one parent, and the tree is only linked in one direction.

So by simply replacing all non-owning `&` references with owning `Box`es, this is what you get:

```rust
pub enum JSb<Item> {
    Start(Item),
    Move(Jbs<Item>),
}

pub struct Jbs<Item> {
    before: Box<JSb<Item>>,
    after: Item,
}

impl<Item> Jbs<Item> {
    pub fn new(before: Box<JSb<Item>>, after: Item) -> Self {
        Jbs { before, after }
    }
}

fn hello() -> JSb<u8> {
    let mut res = JSb::Start(3);

    for i in 1..3 {
        let x = JSb::Move(Jbs::new(Box::new(res), i));
        res = x
    }
    res
}
```

Although that's probably not going to be enough, as you already mentioned that this is supposed to be a tree.

In that case solving this is harder, and you'll probably have to rethink your data structure. It isn't possible to return ownership to the entire tree by returning a **leaf**. (I'm making the assumption here that you intended to have multiple `before`s reference the same parent element to make this a tree)

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of this, I will try to use it and add more operations on it:

```
pub trait OnPath {
  fn id(&self) -> String;
}

pub struct BsFile<Item> {
  id: String,
  i: Item
}
pub struct BsPath<Item>(Vec<BsFile<Item>>);
pub struct BsTree<Item>(Vec<BsPath<Item>>);

impl<Item: OnPath> BsFile<Item> {

  fn new(i: Item) -> Self {
    BsFile {
      id: i.id(),
      i
    }
  }
}

impl<Item: OnPath> BsPath<Item> {
  pub const EMPTY: BsPath<Item> = BsPath(Vec::new());

  pub fn push(&mut self, a: Item) {
    self.0.push(BsFile::new(a))
  }
}

impl<Item> BsTree<Item> {
  pub fn new(paths: Vec<BsPath<Item>>) -> Self {
    BsTree(paths)
  }
}
```